# Redshift "invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.event_type AS e1, b.event_type
AS e2, c.event_type AS e3, d.experiments as Experiment
 FROM (SELECT * FROM next3 WHERE row_number=1) AS a
 JOIN (SELECT * FROM next3 WHERE row_number=2) AS b
 ON a.user_id = b.user_id
 JOIN (SELECT * FROM next3 WHERE row_number=3) AS c
 ON a.user_id = c.user_id
 JOIN (SELECT experiments from new_users) as d
 on new_users.user_id=c.user_id
```

New_Users

```
user_id     :platform   :experiment
19201098735 :web        :
19203549751 :web        :gh|ntn
```

Next3

```
user_id    :event_type          :row_number
19201098735:NewUser             :1
19201098735:AboutUsViewed       :2
19201098735:HomeViewed          :3
19203549751:NewUser             :1
19203549751:HomeViewed          :2
19203549751:SessionAuthenticated:3
```

Desired result:

```
user_id     :E1     :E2             :E3                     :Experiment  
19201098735 :NewUser:AboutUsViewed  :HomeViewed             :
19203549751 :NewUser:HomeViewed     :SessionAuthenticated   :gh|ntn
```

I've run this a bunch of ways -- note I'm an analyst trying to work with data more than a manager building the system, so not the greatest SQL coder. 
There's a view of all events, that I've pulled down to those that were eligible to see an experiment, then pulled back all their events after that. Then I want to convert 3 rows of events to 3 columns, and add the experiment seen as a new 4th column. It's the new_Users join that keeps failing.

Comment: Short answer: you dont need all these subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  MIN(CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN event_type END) as E1,
  MIN(CASE WHEN row_number = 2 THEN event_type END) as E2,
  MIN(CASE WHEN row_number = 3 THEN event_type END) as E3,
  Experiment  
FROM New_Users, Next3
GROUP BY user_id, experiment
ORDER BY user_id
```

Explanation:

- You want an output of one row per user, but you want to join information from multiple rows together. Therefore, use `GROUP BY` to say that you want one row per user
- The two tables are **cross-joined**. This means that every row in `New_Users` is joined with every row in `Next3`. This means there are now lots of rows being selected! For example, 100 users x 3 rows = 300 rows. But don't panic! The `GROUP BY` will reduce it back down to one row per user.
- The `CASE` statement can look confusing, but it's basically saying "Hey, of all the rows for this user, look at the ones where `row_number = 1`, then find the `MIN` (minimum) value in that set, and return it. If the row_number is not 1, ignore it." It's a neat trick to reduce data from multiple rows into one row. The `MIN` function could be anything (SUM, AVG, MAX) -- you just need something to output a single value. It's like using `SUM(price)` to get a single value as a result, but combined with the `CASE` statement it's only going to calculate the answer based on one line.

Comment: That absolutely worked, and was a lot faster than the bungle of joins I was working with.  I did have to add experiment in the group by statement, but all good.Thanks!

Comment: Oops! You're right. The `GROUP BY` must include all fields except those that have a function (that reduces multiple rows down to one row).